# Solve congruence equation where unknown variable is in both sides of congruent operator

Tags: nt.number-theory, congruences

I am trying to solve the following equation:

$(a*n + c) \mod (b-n) \equiv 0$

and $n$ must be the lowest value in $[0, b-1]$

for example $a=17$, $c=-59$ and $b=128$, the solution is $n=55$

$n=b-1$ will be always a solution, because $m \mod 1 \equiv 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, you want to solve in integers
$$  y (b-n) = an+c$$
This is equivalent to
$$ (y+a)(b-n) = ab+c $$
You want $b-n$ to be as large as possible subject to $b-n \le b$.  Thus you want to 
factor $ab+c$ and take its largest divisor $\le b$.  In your example, $ab+c = 2117 = 29 \cdot 73$ whose largest divisor $\le 128$ is $73$, so $n = 128 - 73 = 55$.